# A program that was previously running fine on my system gets stuck in a loop upon starting, even after thorough reinstalls

Tags: windows-registry, windows-11

The program in question is called `MasterPlus`, it's a utility for changing settings on various CoolerMaster products, my use would be accessing my mouse's settings. I'm currently on a very fresh Windows 11 install after a CPU upgrade. The only version available for this app from CoolerMaster is 1.8.7, but I have tried installing older versions that ran into the same problem.

More about the problem: Upon launching the .exe a window pops up with the text "Initializing", the UI for the app appears, either for a split second or for several seconds, but it abruptly disappears at some point, at which the initial window can be seen again and the whole process repeats.

I first noticed this behaviour today, after I reinstalled the program due to it loading very slowly and overall being unresponsive. I then tried closing every app I had running (save for Windows Defender), to no avail. (I also closed every app on subsequent tries after reinstalling)

Since then I have tried the following procedure a couple of times:

- Uninstalled the app through its own uninstaller (tried this both with cache and preferences deleted and kept)
- Performed a quick clenaup with `Disk Clean-up` -> Clean up system files
- Ran `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth` in cmd with admin priviliges
- Performed a manual registry cleanup in the `Registry Editor` by searching for `MasterPlus` and deleting any entries that I found (and could delete)
- Used `Everything` to search for any remaining mention of `MasterPlus` and deleted everything left over (save for entries under Windows\Prefetch)

After all of this, I was only left with a couple of seemingly unmodifiable and undeletable entries in registry at `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\bam\State\UserSettings\`.

After doing this a couple of times I'm still stuck on the same issue as before.

I'm assuming the app isn't completely broken since it worked just fine previously.

What else could I try to get it working?

Comment: Frankly, I'd search or ask here: https://community.coolermaster.com/ for example?

Comment: Also, if you want to try another, general-purpose, mouse tool, free X-Mouse Button Control, https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm, might be an altternative. It works well with my Logitech mouses, though the OEM software from Logitech did not (and the file is *huge*).

Answer (score 1):

Other people have run into the same problem.

In the post
[MasterPlus v1.8.4 not responding](https://www.reddit.com/r/coolermaster/comments/xsxngr/masterplus_v184_not_responding_the_only_device/),
the solution was to run MasterPlus as Administrator for the
Initializing phase to finish, by right-click on its executable
and selecting "Run as Administrator".
The poster doesn't say if he had to run it this way every time,
or just once.

In the post
[Fix for Coolermaster Masterplus 1.6.7 not opening on Windows 10](https://www.reddit.com/r/coolermaster/comments/pkrqna/fix_for_coolermaster_masterplus_167_not_opening/),
the poster went as far as installing version 1.0.6 and blocking
updates.

Comment: I tried what worked for others in the 2 linked threads but they didn't do anything for me sadly

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the [system internals process monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).
2. Filter with "Process is EXENAME" or "Process contains EXENAME" .. my guess is that "process contains MasterPlus" would do but I do not know if the exe name matches.
3. Run it.
4. Add more filters if needed (you will know).
5. See what it was last doing when it hung.

If you still can't figure it out, you will need to post a stack trace (here) and an engineer can look at it and tell you.  This might not solve the problem either depending on what it is doing in the stack but someone that can read a stack trace can at least tell you what it is busy trying to do.

Comment: I did what you recommended and even poked around a bit in registry to see if it was getting stuck on just a single variable missing but the problem still stands. I forwarded the information I found using ProcMon and a log file the app makes to a CM representative in the meanwhile

Comment: @devor110 , if you did what I said, you wouldn't need to "poke around".  Sometimes procmon can be overwhelming but it almost always has the answer if you can figure out how to use it effectively.  Be creative with the filters to make the data digestible.   For instance, look at things that are not equal to success.  What is the last thing is started doing?  The logs sure would help.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue, nothing here or in any Reddit thread fixed it.

Creating a new Windows user and using M++ there worked flawlessly.

No clue what causes this, but it works ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score -1):

One more uninstall you could try is with [BCUninstaller](https://www.bcuninstaller.com/). Clean all the leftovers or at least the safe ones when asked. That could help getting rid of some broken registry keys or files you don't know about - it's definitely more accurate than searching with Everything.

Also, did you check if there's anything in Windows Event Log? There could be some hints there.